# How to arrange UITableView Sections titles based on plist keys ?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a a plist, with key-values, the keys are strings and values are strings too. 
I wan't the output of the uitableview section titles to be according to  the keys in the plist 
. That said I mean key1-should be the title of section-1, key-2 should be title for section-2 and soon. 
Here is my example plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Settings</key>
    <array>
        <string>one-one</string>
        <string>one-two</string>
    </array>
    <key>Notifications</key>
    <array>
        <string>two-one</string>
        <string>two-two</string>
    </array>
    <key>Info</key>
    <array>
        <string>three_one</string>
        <string>three_two</string>
        <string>three_three</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the code I tried to rearrange in viewDidLoad

```
_

data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *first = [_data valueForKey:@"Settings"];
    NSArray *second = [_data valueForKey:@"Notifications"];
    NSArray *third = [_data valueForKey:@"Info"];
    NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:first, @"Settings",second, @"Notificatitons",third, @"Info",  nil];
    _data = temp;
```

And this is the configuration for table data source

```
#pragma mark - data source 
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_data count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[_data allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *continent = [self tableView:_testTable titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return [[_data valueForKey:continent] count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *rekebishaCell = @"RekebishaCell";
    NSString *continent = [self tableView:_testTable titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *sub_settings = [[_data valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: rekebishaCell];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                       reuseIdentifier:rekebishaCell];
    }
    // config cell ui
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = sub_settings;

    return cell;
}
```

So far I'm getting this 
[image]

This I need this output 
1-Settings 
2-Notifications
3-Info

[image]
Any help I do appreciate, may be I've been staring my screen for quite some time, my brain is missing something, :P

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` does not store key/values in an ordered fashion. If you want them ordered, you'll need to pull them all out and order them using a different structure, most likely an `NSArray`

See this S.O. answer:

[NSDictionary's allKeys array messed up - not in the order they are in the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400920/nsdictionarys-allkeys-array-messed-up-not-in-the-order-they-are-in-the-dictio)

Comment: ...this is the exactly problem I'm facing, I would consider reorganising my data-structrure, my be NSArray is a way to go, thanks for the tip, but let's wait may be someone has done this b4.

Comment: I don't think any one has used an `NSDictionary` in the manner you are describing. I'm fairly certain you're only solution at the moment is to use something other than a dictionary or pull the records out, sort them how you want, and *then* use them as the data source for the table.

Comment: ...Aaron I just wanted to maintain the order of keys in plist. since NSDictionary don't maintain the order of the keys, that is the problem I faced!,  I'm looking to this Article may be it will led me to the right path! http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Comment: If that is the problem you've faced you must also realize that you can't use a dictionary and need to use an array. Yes the subclass in that link that would work. I have used it before. Note, that if you read through the implementation, you'll see that his solution still uses an `NSArray` to maintain the ordering. `NSArray` for ordering is your answer.